# How to change color in PhpStorm for a specific keyword?

Tags: colors, phpstorm

When using Sublime Text 3, I was able to associate different colors to specific keywords, e.g. things like `function` and `array` were light blue, but `switch`, `if` and `return` were set to purple.

In PhpStorm 2016 there seems to be only a single option for keywords. Can this be changed?

Comment: It's not possible to assign specific colors to certain keywords in PhpStorm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @LazyOne mentioned, it's not currently possible. Please vote for [IDEABKL-5473](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5473) and linked tickets

Comment: Even though it didn't solve my problem right now, but I guess voting for that feature is the best option available right now. Let's hope, you can change your answer in the future.